# Running long-time background task in a separate background thread vs process

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm building a ASP.NET Core web application and I need to run some complex tasks that takes quite some time to finish up, from seconds to minutes. The user don't have to wait till the complete task runs but someway I need to update the UI with the progress of the task. I'm thinking of two ways to handle this in the ASP.NET server: one is using a background thread and another is using a separate process. I don't want the long running task hamper the web application in any way. Is using a thread is a safe option compared to a process? or running these tasks in a separate process is a better and efficient way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say do it in another process. Put it in a queue and have a separate process handle that queue and when finished signal the web app by posting a job complete message or something.

If you use a regular thread inside the web app and the server is shutdown in the middle of the process, or the web app is recycled you might get some undesired effects.

Some other options are outlined [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should think differently, in such situation always think about real time notifications approaches like signalR by which you can fire your request and you dont have to worry about it anymore, and once it's done it's gonna signal your app and you'll have access to all the data which you can manipulate based on your business. visit this link for more info [An Introduction to SignalR](https://www.google.com.sa/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwik5cPKyvnVAhXGWxoKHTZzDQIQFggkMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Faspnet%2Fsignalr%2Foverview%2Fgetting-started%2Fintroduction-to-signalr&usg=AFQjCNE6fb3R_hOjVek39Glo7t-CZmJ3Hw)